# PDF File Corrupted after Generated from ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I am trying to simply generate pdf file on windows from the command below:

```
convert 1.png mypdf.pdf
```

But when I open the generated pdf, it says `Something went wrong`. See the image below

[image]

Comment: What version of ImageMagick?  What platform/OS? What viewer of the PDF are you using?

Comment: it's 7.0.11 for windows 64 bit

Comment: What viewer are you using to view the PDF?  Can you post an example PNG that has this issue? What exact version of Imagemagick 7.0.11.x?

Comment: @fmw42 ImageMagick 7.0.11-5 Q16 x64 2021-03-28. I am using browser to open pdf.

Comment: What browser and on what platform/OS?

Comment: Can you post the PNG that is causing issues?

Comment: @fmw42 I tried in Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Both are updated. Why PNG matter? It was random picture from google. I don't have it right now.

Comment: I wanted to be sure it was not some issue with your input. I have no issues converting PNG or JPG etc to PDF on my Mac OSX Sierra with Imagemagick 7.0.11.6 Q16

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure ImageMagick to work with AEM Assets. Then open the generated PDF using [Adobe Acrobat Reader](http://acrobat.adobe.com) or any other document viewer, but Adobe Acrobat is recommended because it is developed by Adobe Inc. who also developed the Portable Document Format (PDF) in 1993.